# create a table with key value in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multidimensional-array

my little problem is.

I get data and I filters jusqu'la all okay.

and I want the results in Table mettres
example of the desired result:

```
data:[
 {
  id=1,
  name="toto"
 },
 {
  id=1,
  name="toto"
 }
]
```

etc. ..
so I already try to make a simple table but it keeps me just last Elements, I do not see where I made ​​a mistake.
this is what I did

```
NSArray *array1;
for (int i=0; i<[catg count]; i++) {
 if ([ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Expositions" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] ==        NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Peinture / Illustration" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Photographie" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Spectacles" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ) {

  array1 = @[@"data",@{@"id": catg[i][@"id"],@"name": catg[i][@"name"]}];
  }
}
```

Thks

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting array1 in each iteration of your loop

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<[catg count]; i++) {
 if ([ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Expositions" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] ==        NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Peinture / Illustration" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Photographie" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Spectacles" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ) {

  NSArray *tempArray = @[@"data",@{@"id": catg[i][@"id"],@"name": catg[i][@"name"]}];
  [array1 addObject:tempArray];
  }
}
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: I think with your code, you will have at the end in 'array1' something like : [{@"data", ...}, {@"data", ...}]

Answer (score 0):

For every loop you set your array.
Try to modify your code like this :

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray allo] init];
for (int i=0; i<[catg count]; i++) {
 if ([ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Expositions" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] ==        NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Peinture / Illustration" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Photographie" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ||
     [ catg[i][@"name"] compare:@"Spectacles" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ) {

  [array1 addObject:@[@{@"id": catg[i][@"id"],@"name": catg[i][@"name"]}]];
  }
}

NSDictionary *result = @{@"data": array1};
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

ps : Nice google translate with French words :p

Answer (score 0):

yes,

but it made ​​me a thing like this

```
data,
            {
        id = 1;
        name ="toto";
    }
),
    (
    data,
            {
        id = 8;
        name = "titi";
    }
)
```

and I would like to

```
data:[
            {
        id = 1;
        name ="toto";
    },
    data,
            {
        id = 8;
        name = "titi";
    }
]
```

it would be another way to do this?

thks